# How to create a frame around custom marker icons without use of shadows

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How would you put a white frame behind a dynamically loaded marker icon, now, that the new Google Maps "VisualRefresh" doesn´t allow shadows anymore? [1](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics)

Open http://jsfiddle.net/FSffv/3/ with *google.maps.visualRefresh = false;* to see the white frame around the marker icon and *google.maps.visualRefresh = true;* to have it disappear.

```
var map;
var m_NormalImageSize = 15;
var m_NormalShadowSize = m_NormalImageSize+5;
var elevator;
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 6,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(47, 8),
  mapTypeId: 'terrain'
};

// turn VisualRefresh on/off
google.maps.visualRefresh = false;

map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], myOptions);
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQUnmYVY5sWfZtBlw_IELax3W8E7-jZcCXLd2HUZYtpk_AeuK4CRnJmMHj0";
var img_ratio = img.height / img.width;
if (isNaN(img_ratio)) 
  img_ratio = 1;
var icon_size = new google.maps.Size(m_NormalImageSize, m_NormalImageSize * img_ratio);
var shadow_size = new google.maps.Size(m_NormalShadowSize, m_NormalShadowSize * img_ratio);
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  "http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQUnmYVY5sWfZtBlw_IELax3W8E7-jZcCXLd2HUZYtpk_AeuK4CRnJmMHj0",
  icon_size,
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(-3, m_NormalImageSize * img_ratio + 3 * img_ratio),
  icon_size
);

// the frame around the marker icon as a shadow
var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
  "http://alsotoday.com/jpg/placemarkbackground_white.png",
  shadow_size,
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(0, m_NormalShadowSize * img_ratio),
  shadow_size
);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(47, 8),
  map: map,
  icon: image,
  shadow: shadow,
  title: "hallo"
 });
```

Comment: If the icon is always to have a white border, then simply prepare the artwork with the border already in place. If icon(s) are dynamically generated, then server-side utilities are available for adding borders.

Comment: So where does the artowrk for the icon(s) come from?

Comment: Thanks for the hint about merging the image with the frame by PHP. But the frame around the image is just styling of the page, and should not change the content (images) of the page. 

For instance, when I want to display live-Tweets on a map, the icons (profile-pictures) are dynamically loaded from Twitter, and Tweets change every second or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use a custom HTML overlay. Then you can style it any way you like.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/vEhfE/6/) using this code:

```
function ImageMarker( options ) {
    this.setValues( options );

    this.$inner = $('<div>').css({
        position: 'relative',
        left: '-50%', top: '-50%',
        fontSize: '1px',
        lineHeight: '1px',
        border: '2px solid red',
        padding: '2px',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        cursor: 'default'
    });

    this.$div = $('<div>')
        .append( this.$inner )
        .css({
            position: 'absolute',
            display: 'none'
        });
};

ImageMarker.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView;

ImageMarker.prototype.onAdd = function() {
    $( this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget ).append( this.$div );
};

ImageMarker.prototype.onRemove = function() {
    this.$div.remove();
};

ImageMarker.prototype.draw = function() {
    var marker = this;
    var projection = this.getProjection();
    var position = projection.fromLatLngToDivPixel( this.get('position') );

    this.$div.css({
        left: position.x,
        top: position.y,
        display: 'block'
    })

    this.$inner
        .html( '<img src="' + this.get('image') + '"/>' )
        .click( function( event ) {
            var events = marker.get('events');
            events && events.click( event );
        });
};

function initialize() {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng( 40.708762, -74.006731 );

    var map = new google.maps.Map( $('#map_canvas')[0], {
        zoom: 15,
        center: latLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker = new ImageMarker({
        map: map,
        position: latLng,
        image: 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico',
        events: {
            click: function( event ) {
                alert( 'Clicked marker' );
            }
        }
    });
};

$( initialize );
```

Comment: This is cool advanced google.maps.OverlayView() stuff, but can I position multiple markers by Lat/Long with this?

Comment: Yes, where it has the `var marker = new ImageMarker({...})` you could create any number of markers in the same way, passing in a different `position` and `image` for each.

Comment: Fascinating. Will try it on my site. Thanks!

Comment: This method gives great styling options for custom marker icons. Question still is, how the performance will be for 50 - 100 markers.

Comment: That is a good question! I don't actually know how it will fare with that many markers. I will be curious to hear how it works out. Another way to do it would be to use a `canvas` overlay and draw the markers yourself. That would handle many hundreds of markers easily. But let's see how this version does first.

Comment: W̶orks i̶̶n̶̶c̶̶r̶̶e̶̶d̶̶i̶̶b̶̶l̶̶y̶  ridiculously good: http://alsotoday.com/villingen/

Comment: That's a nice map! Great work, it's good to see it in action. And thanks for the mention in the source code. :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about having one more image with borders and make a statement like below:

```
if (google.maps.visualRefresh) {
    image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        "http://s24.postimg.org/lfamj2ktd/image.png",
    icon_size,
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(-3, m_NormalImageSize * img_ratio + 3 * img_ratio),
    icon_size);
}
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/FSffv/4/).

Comment: (See my comment under the question)

Comment: @AlexanderRoehnisch I know you have got your answer.  But I waned to show what I've tried for you.  Got it. Actually I was trying to use the blend.js to merge images.  But I was unsuccessful and therefore showed the idea to you.

Comment: @AlexanderRoehnisch Actually from the time you posted the question I was trying to find a optimized approach and also waiting for someone to give nice optimized solution.  Once Michael Geary posted his answer, I posted my idea :)

Comment: Nice! This is definitely a "why didn't I think of that?" moment. :-) @AlexanderRoehnisch - definitely try out this method too - and if it works out for your app, please feel free to make this the accepted answer instead of mine.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Thank you for sharing your comments on my work.